# Where in Kaer Morhen can I find my guests?

Tags: the-witcher-3

At some points you have the option to send certain people to Kaer Morhen, in my case I did this with

> Triss and Keira

Now I'm at the point where I can revisit Kaer Morhen, but I can't find any of them there. Where exactly are they?

Answer (score 10):

I was searching for the same but having explored what I believe was the whole area of Kaer Morhen, I could not find them anywhere either. My conclusion is that the chronological implications in this game are simply badly implemented because this was not the only occasion when the plot didn't make sense and expected characters to be somewhere where they weren't, for example

> Triss in Novigrad during the Redania's Most Wanted quest or Yen in Skellige during some of the side quests there.

I believe that sending people to Kaer Morhen serves only to prepare for

> the Battle of Kaer Morhen (the Brothers in Arms: Area quests)

and the game doesn't acknowledge their presence before the respective main quest.

The story in this game is very enjoyable but at the same time it's very easy to miss important scenes. For example, I completely missed

> Letho

and never expected that something as simple as

> bringing Ciri to see Emhyr var Emreis

would result in a completely different main ending.